# Drupal Views alter Filter to CAST() string as Float

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7, view, hook

i got a problem, altering my view so that it is filtering a string-field (where i know that there only can be numbers, but can't change this scenario) so that it is handled as number...

normaly i can achieve this by using "CAST" ... the problem is, that it gets altered in the hook so that my example looks like the following:

```
... AND (CASTfield_data_field_baserent.field_baserent_valueASDECIMAL <= '1000') ))
```

so all extra characters get stripped out... :-/

i tried a lot of hooks but none of them seem to do the job! 
Does anyone have a idea, how i can do it?! 
(the module computed field is not really an option..)

my current code is like the following:

```
function custom_helpers_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){
if($view->name=="mietangebote"){
    // Miete
        if(!empty($view->exposed_raw_input['field_baserent_value'])){
            foreach($query->where[1]['conditions'] as $key=>$condition){
                if($condition['field']=="field_data_field_baserent.field_baserent_value"){
                    $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['operator']="<=";
                    $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['value']=(double)$view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['value'];
                    $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['field']="CAST(".$view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['field']." AS DECIMAL)";
                    //dpm($view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where

```
$view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['field']="CAST(".$view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['field']." AS DECIMAL)";
```

is the important line

THANKS in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

`hook_views_query_alter` function should do the job, here is what it should look like:

```
function custom_helpers_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ( $view->name == 'mietangebote' ) {

    // Miete
    if(!empty($view->exposed_raw_input['field_baserent_value'])){

      foreach($query->where[1]['conditions'] as $key => $condition) {
        if ( $condition['field'] == 'field_data_field_baserent.field_baserent_value' ) {
          $query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['operator'] = 'formula';
          $query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['value'] = array(':val' => (double)$query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['value']); 
          $query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['field'] = 'CAST(' . $query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['field'] . ' AS UNSIGNED) >= :val';
          //dpm($view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]);
          break; 
        }
      }

      // For sorting as well
      foreach($query->orderby as $key => $condition) {
        if ( $condition['field'] == 'field_data_field_count_field_count_value' ) {              
          $query->orderby[$key]['field'] = 'CAST(' . $query->orderby[$key]['field'] . ' AS UNSIGNED)'; 
          break; 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The important line is:

```
$query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['operator'] = 'formula';
```

and will allow Views to treat the value of 'field' as an SQL snippet and not as a field's name. Check the source code of `add_where_expression` for the full details!  [[doc]](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3A%3Aadd_where_expression/7.x-3.x)

And good luck!

**Disclaimer**: This answer is a variation of a very similar one to this [question from drupal.stackexchange.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201475/treating-string-field-as-numeric-to-use-as-an-exposed-filter). The code is modified to address the specific question (not just copy+paste).

Answer (score 0):

See if there's any way to pass the condition yourself, something like this:

```
$view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]->condition("CAST(".$view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['field']." AS DECIMAL) <= " . $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CAST`, simply build an expression with `0+` tacked onto the variable and/or constant:

```
0+'1000'
```

will be treated as the *numeric* value `1000`, not the *string* `'1000'`.